# Multiplication operator is closed

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-theory

Let $\Omega$ be an unbounded subset of $\mathbb{C}$. Consider the Hilbert space $H=L^{2}(\Omega)$ and the (unbounded) multiplication operator $T$ given as follows:

$Tf(z)=zf(z), f(z)\in D(T)$ where $D(T)=\{f\in L^{2}(\Omega):\int_{\Omega}|zf(z)|^{2}d\mu<\infty\}$.

It can be shown that $D(T)$ is dense in $L^{2}$. The next question is to show that $T$ is a closed operator.

Let $f_{n}\in D(T)$ and $f_{n}\longrightarrow f$, $f\in L^{2}$ and $Tf_{n}\longrightarrow g$, $g\in L^{2}$, where convergence is in the $L^{2}$ norm. How do I show that $f \in D(T)$ and that $Tf=g$?

In particular, I must show that $\int_{\Omega}|zf(z)|^{2}d\mu$ is finite given that $\int_{\Omega}|zf_{n}(z)|^{2}d\mu$ is finite $\forall n$, and $\lim_{n\to\infty}\int_{\Omega}|f_{n}(z)-f(z)|^{2}d\mu=0$.

My doubt arises from the fact that $\Omega$ is not bounded.

I would be grateful for hints.

Comment: I get $|zf(z)|^{2}\leq (|zf_{n}(z)-zf(z)|+|zf_{n}(z)|)^{2}$. Also, $f_{n}$ convergence  to $f$ in $L^{2}$ norm, so how does it follow that $zf_{n}$ converges to $zf(z)$ in $L^{2}$ norm?

Comment: You don't really need to show separately that $\int_\Omega \vert zf(z)\vert^2d\mu<\infty$. What you have to do is to show that $g(z)=zf(z)$ almost everywhere. Use the fact that if a sequence is convergent in $L^2$, then it has an almost everywhere convergent subsequence.

Comment: Thank you, I've got it now!

Comment: That's fine. You're welcome!